# Can not update data using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have written some code for updating my database value using ajax and codeigniter when I edit the value after double clicking on it.

**Query:**
I want to update column **dc_no** under table **sale_detail** when i click on the value under column **dc_no**. Now, i can only change the value of variable only once. second time when i try to update value, nothing happens. Here **dc_no** is of ***float*** type. Below is the code i have written:

**View/Ajax:**

```
<td id="<?php echo $object['dc_no'];?>" ondblclick="divDblClick5(this)"><?php echo $object['dc_no'];?></td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var dc_no = "<?php echo $object['dc_no'];?>";
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $object['dc_no'];?>').val = dc_no;
            function divDblClick5(target)
            {
                var new_dc_no=prompt("Please enter New DC",dc_no);
                dc_no = new_dc_no;
                document.getElementById(target.id).val = dc_no;
                $.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  url: "dcsaleedit",
                  cache: false,    
                  data: { dc: target.id, dc_no: dc_no},
                  success: function(response){

                    alert(response);
                    // window.location.reload();

                },
                error: function()
                {     
                  alert('Error while request..');
                }
                });

              }
            </script>
```

Here, I have used variable id for .

**Controller:**

```
public function dcsaleedit()
    {
        $dc = $this->input->post('dc');
        var_dump($dc);
        $dc_no = $this->input->post('dc_no');
        $fdc = (float)$dc_no;
        $update_array = array('dc_no' => $fdc);
        $this->User_model->update_dcsale($dc, $update_array);
   }
```

I have also checked that I am getting an input or not. And I am successfully getting the values. I have converted **_dc_no_** into float from string because dc_no is of *float* data type.

**Model:**

```
public function update_dcsale($dc, $update_array)
        {
            $this->db->where('dc_no',$dc);
            return $this->db->update('sale_details', $update_array);
        }
```

I also checked the returned value from model by var_dump() which is showing true. So, I am not getting that where I am getting problem.

Comment: Try adding print last query in your model.

Answer (score 0):

your ajax url is not correct. you need to show ajax a proper path.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed from Azad Khan, the url is not right.
You're writing a webapp, right?
So you're working with the http protocol that from w3c or http 1.1 documents states that the url has the following syntax:

```
protocol://domainName:port/uri
http://yoursite.com/routeWhereYouUpload
```

is not mandatory to specify :80 for http, so change

```
url: "dcsaleedit"
```

with

```
url: "localhost:9000/nameOfProject/controller.php/dcsaleedit"
```

obviously localhost:9000 is the path you access developing with xampp,wampp,vagrant or apache, I don't know your developing environment,you will have to adjust it for yourself, just put the path to access your controller.php ( that is not `c:/xampp/htdocs/project` but `localhost:port/project/controller/route`

Comment: nope. it is going to the function in controller correctly. I have checked that.